# Tag Manager variables with a lot of possibilities

Tags: google-tag-manager

I'm quite new to Google Tag Manager and I currently have a search interface where users can select different options. Creating tags for say, the colors red, blue and yellow is easy. But I'm having a problem with this interface, I would like to fire tags for each possibility when they appear in the data layer, the problem being that I have more than 100 possibilities referring to cities.

So for instance;

```
dataLayer.push({
   "city" : "Montreal"
})
```

The problem being that "Montreal" can be 100 other cities. Do I need to manually create a tag for each of the cities? I would like to track what users select in this interface, am I going the wrong way about this?

Comment: As this is Stack Overflow, can you show more code with how the selection works? This doesn't sound like it needs to be triggered by the dataLayer. Maybe there's a specific class, ID, or attribute that you could use for your trigger, rather than the city name.

Comment: I'm not sure what you are trying to achive but you can make your own custom dataLayer variable {{city}} which will read city value stored in datalayer. Then you can just use this variable anywhere you want.

Comment: We want to track users' interaction with this interface. When a user selects an option, I push the datalayer with whatever that option might be. The customer I'm dealing with is convinced that Google Tag Manager will be the solution to all their problems, which frankly, I don't understand.

If I want to track each city option individually, wouldn't it be fair to say that I'd need to create 100 city tags that will each be triggered by their respective city variable?

Comment: Note that you can avoid using the dataLayer if you are able to scrape the DOM for what you need and from what you're describing, this method sounds simple enough to be more efficient than using the dataLayer (IMO). But if you are sure you want to use the dataLayer, then you would need a Custom HTML tag set up to listen to clicks on those options, and then you would push the selection into the dataLayer (along with an 'event' key to help make the triggering simple).